# Enabling Scala continuations in SBT 0.13 gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, sbt

After some googling I've the following in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true

libraryDependencies +=
    compilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.10.3-RC3")

scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

My code compiles, but I face the following error when I try to run:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.continuations.package$.shift error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the configuration for the compiler plugin to be part of your project, i.e. in `project.sbt` or `build.sbt`:

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true

libraryDependencies +=
  compilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.10.3-RC3")

scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I was doing something like having it in the wrong file, but when I tried moving it I accidentally called build.sbt build.scala, which gave other errors of course.

Phew